# How to update control on the page in wpf from own .cs file?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to update a label control, on a "WPF" page, from my own .cs file but not updating .Please help me.I have a page "Measurements.xaml" ,after page load,in button click create object for my own cs file(sample.cs) and called a method in the cs file.In that method i am trying to update lable control on page (Measurements.xaml),as below

```
((Measurements)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).label1.Content = "153";
```

Measurements.xaml is not a window.

Comment: please elaborate your issue and share some code what and how you are trying to achieve.

Comment: take the goomba and put it on the flootzel.  Also, show us some code, cause what you posted could mean any number of things.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have done or how, but this should work:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sample = new Sample();
        sample.UpdateLabel();
    }
}

class Sample
{
    public void UpdateLabel()
    {
        var main = (MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow;
        main.Label1.Content = "153";
    }
}
```